# Random Variable: Ordered List of ints.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

You are given an ordered list of integers : 1, 2, ...100. You then randomly permute (reorder) the integers.

a.) Define a random variable that indicates whether or not a pair of integers in the list is permuted. 
    What distribution should the random variable have if this reordering is to be completely random?

b.) How many such random variables should you define for this list?

c.) What is the expected # of permutations of 2 particular integers in the list?

d.) Define the random variable that describes the total number of permutations in this list. 
    What is the probability mass function if you assume that each individual permutation is independent of each other?

e.) What is the expected number of permutations in this list. Justify your answer.

f.) What is the standard deviation of the number of permutations in the list?

g.) You observe 1000 pairs. Is that a very likely outcome? Justify your answer.

I'm confused about the phrasing of this question. Specifically for part a, when it says "whether or not a pair of integers in the list is permuted", does it just mean if either a or b is not in the correct spot? Also just general guidance to solving this would be great.

Comment: You have a reasonable question; why not ask the person who created this question? "A pair $(a,b)$ is permuted" could mean $1 - P(a,b \mbox{ are fixed})$ or $1 - P(a \mbox{ or } b \mbox{ is fixed})$ or even $P(\pi(a) = b \mbox{ and } \pi(b) = a)$ ($\pi$ being the permutation). Get the person who originally asked you this to clarify.